# Do I have to find different integral limits for $x , y$ in the following double integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find  $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}|x+y|\, {\rm d}x\, {\rm d}y$$
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtdkK.png)

In the following image there is a double integral of an absolute value. I am not sure how to define the limits of the integral

Comment: An absolute value is just a shorthand for a piecewise function: split the integral into the regions where $x + y$ is positive and where it's negative and use the definition of the absolute value on both.

Comment: The double integral already has limits of integration, ones that describe the square region $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$.  So it is unclear what "how to define the limits of the integral" means for your problem.  Would you clarify that,e.g. if you have a different region in mind?

Answer (score 2):

The line $y = -x$ separates the region where $x + y$ is positive from the region where it is negative. So we can define two triangular regions and assign the appropriate function $f$ to these:

$I$: $f(x,y) = -x-y \qquad$ for $-1 < y < -x \qquad$ and $-1 < x < 1$.

$II$: $f(x,y) = x+y \qquad$ for $-x < y < 1 \qquad$  and $-1 < x < 1$.

It is now straightforward to perform the double integrals over regions $I$ and $II$ and take the sum. In both regions I obtain the result $4/3$, hence the final answer is $8/3$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}|x+y|\, {\rm d}x\, {\rm d}y &= 2 \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-x}^{1}(x+y)\, {\rm d}y\, {\rm d}x\\
 & = \int_{-1}^{1}\left[2xy+y^2\right]_{-x}^{1} \, {\rm d}x \\
 & = \int_{-1}^{1}(x^2+2x+1) \, {\rm d}x\\
 & = \left[\frac{x^3}3+x^2+x\right]_{-1}^{1} = \frac83.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If you use

$$ \int |u|u^n\,du=\frac{|u|u^{n+1}}{n+2} +c$$

you may find the integral as follows.

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-1}^1|x+y|\,dx&=&\left[\frac{|x+y|(x+y)}{2}\right]_{-1}^1\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left[|1+y|(1+y)-|-1+y|(-1+y)\right]+c
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
 &&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1|1+y|(1+y)-|-1+y|(-1+y)\,dy\\
 &=&\frac{1}{6}\left[|1+y|(1+y)^2|-1+y|(-1+y)^2\right]_{-1}^1\\
 &=&\frac{8}{3}
\end{eqnarray}